# Magento 2: Permissions to add/edit customers is missing despite administrator role

Tags: magento2, admin, permissions, magento2.4.2

In my Magento 2.4.2 shop I'm not allowed to add or edit customers. Although I'm logged in as an administrator.
When opening the `customer` or `sales` page, all customer information are obfuscated.

[image]

When I try to create a new customer, I get the following message:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to view this page.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: A possible solution - but are you behind a firewall that is a bit ramped up like sucuri? Or is the Access Denied a Magento page error?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - nice guess. The actual reason was a GDPR module which was installed with the theme. See my answer for details.

Comment: Good spot. I hate it when you get a situation like that

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: I am using the theme `creativestyle/magesuite` which installed the extension `creativestyle/magesuite-gdpr`which was responsible for the obfuscation.

To overcome the issue, a new user role was defined under `System -> Permissions -> User Roles`. There you have to uncheck the GDPR specific options.

[image]